# could not resolve constructor JSONTokener(InuputStream)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, org.json

```
new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(getclass().getResource("/identification/carrier.json").openStream());
```

I have this code. It was working a couple of days ago. There were some other changes and errors. Added some dependencies to the pom etc. Now its not working.

I know its using JSONTokener from some other library. But when I remove the import and try to add again. I doesnt gives me the option to use JSONTokener from org.json which has InputStream construction.

It only shows two options one org.json from hive second org.codehaus.jetti.json. both of them dont support the InputStream construction.

I don't know where to fix the issue? Im using IntelliJ and its a maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Local History of pom.xml (right click inside file, then **Local History** > **Show Local History**) and check how it was looking "a couple of days ago".

Comment: is there any way to check the classpath. I think the wrong library was added to the local path of the project that's why it's getting confused.